# Trouble analyzing complexity of arbitrary algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I've been reading the CLRS algorithm book and I decided to try out a problem for myself. I've been trying to use a new method to help understand the complexity of the arbitrary algorithm, displayed below. Here is my method:

**Line-by-line Analysis:**

`Line 2. Sum of natural numbers.` Theta (N)

`Line 3. Sum of squares.` Theta (N<sup>2</sup>)

`Line 4. If j is divisible by i.` Theta (**?**)

`Line 5. Sum of natural numbers.` Theta (N)

**Algorithm**:

```
1. sum = 0
2. for i=1 to n do
3.    for j=1 to i2 do
4.       if(j(mod i) == 0) then
5.          for k=1 to j do
6.             sum++
```

As you can tell, I'm trying to find the number of times `sum++` is executed, and it's **Line 4** that is throwing me off. Could someone guide me a little bit?

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320420/time-complexity-of-a-modulo-operation

Comment: Hint: there are `x / i` numbers `<= x` that are divisibile (mod `i` = 0) by `i`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplifying Summation from loop with an if statment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789396/simplifying-summation-from-loop-with-an-if-statment)

Comment: Your method (multiplying worst-case complexities of each loop), although it gives the correct answer in many simple cases, is not in general valid. `for (i=1; i <n; i*=2) { for (j=1; j<i; j++) { sum++ }}` is an example where this method doesn't work... giving O(n log n) rather than O(n).

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You don't know how to calculate the complexity or what is `mod`?

Comment: I do not know how to calculate this complexity. I know what mod is, but the if statement is throwing me off when I try to keep track of how many times `sum++` will execute.